# Find the numbers whose sum equal to 2024 to help Giap and Thin win

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Giap secretly gave the judges seven natural distinct numbers whose sum equal to
> $2024$ and enable to show Thin the forth largest one. Find the forth
> largest that can help Thin guess all the numbers of Giap.

It's my City Test for Mathematic. There are many solutions on the Internet, but they have a little bit problem.

Let $a<b<c<d<e<f<g$ are the numbers of Giap. If the natural numbers don't contain $0$ then we have a nice solution:

Very easy to see $a+b+c \ge 1+2+3=6$, and $d+e+f+g \ge d+(d+1)+(d+2)+(d+3)=4d+6$. So if the choose $d=503$ then $a+b+c+d+e+f+g \ge 2024$, equality always occur.

So Giap just chooses $1, 2, 3, 503, 504, 505, 506$. The forth largest is $503$ then Thin easily to show the last.

But the problem here is natural numbers contain $0$, so that I cannot know what to do. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you. (I think there exists a set of numbers that can help Thin guess).

Comment: Not everybody considers $0$ a natural number. In fact, I believe the majority consider it NOT to be be a natural number. So, you would want to confirm what convention the test uses.

Comment: Well, the definition of "natural number" is ambiguous.  Some writers include $0$, others do not.  In any case, why doesn't the same approach work if $0$ is involved?

Comment: @Haris in my country, textbooks consider it.

Comment: @lulu I have just seen the solution that I have posted. If you can find another, please tell me :3

Comment: I don't understand.  Use the solution you have provided, just adapt it to recognize that the first three might sum to $0+1+2=3$ instead of $6$.

Comment: The sum is not $2024$. Try $0,1,2,502,503,504,505$ or $0,1,2,504,505,506,507$ both dont work.

Comment: Ok, so then there is no solution with $0\in \mathbb N$.  The problem must have intended $0\not \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: I think there will be a solution that we can't imagine :D

Comment: There can't be gaps between the larger numbers, because you wouldn't know where to place them.  Same with the smaller ones.  This type of solution is the only chance.